# Django Ajax Auth Login

Tags: ajax, django

I'll want to redirect index page after logged in auth user. But don't know how coding the response to data. repeatedly redirect login page

views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def Login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("POST Method")
        username = request.GET.get('username')
        password = request.GET.get('password')
        if username and password:
            # Test username/password combination
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            # Found a match
            if user is not None:
                # User is active
                if user.is_active:
                    # Officially log the user in
                    login(request, user)
                    data = {'success': True}
                    return render_to_response('index/index.html', data, RequestContext(request))
                else:
                    data = {'success': False, 'error': 'User is not active'}
                    return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', data, RequestContext(request))
            else:
                data = {'success': False, 'error': 'Wrong username and/or password'}
            print (data)

            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
    # Request method is not POST or one of username or password is missing
    return render_to_response('accounts/login.html', RequestContext(request))
```

Ajax call : POST ( Is how to login the auth user )

```
    $('#signIn_1').click(function (e) {
        var username = $.trim($('#un_1').val());
        var password = $.trim($('#pw_1').val());

        $.ajax({
            url : "{% 'login' %}",
            type : 'POST',
            data : {
                'username' : username,
                'password' : password
            },
            dataType : 'json',
            success : function (data) {
                if (data != null && data == "success") {
                    window.location = '/'
                }
                else {
                    $('#signIn_1').append(data);
                    alert(data);
                }

            }
        })

    });

})(jQuery);
```

login.html

```
         <div class="form-main">
                            <form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">{% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" id="un_1" class="form-control" placeholder="username" required="required">
                                <input type="password" id="pw_1" class="form-control" placeholder="password" required="required">
                            </div>
                            <button id="signIn_1" type="submit" class="btn btn-block signin">Sign In</button>
                            </form>
                            <div id="message"></div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: why are you doing this `login(request, user)`?

Comment: I want to attach to the current session. this is done with a login() function.

Answer (score 0):

> Please use this for ajax response parsing..

```
 $('#signIn_1').click(function (e) {
    var username = $.trim($('#un_1').val());
    var password = $.trim($('#pw_1').val());

    $.ajax({
        url : "{% 'login' %}",
        type : 'POST',
        data : {
            'username' : username,
            'password' : password
        },
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function (data) {
            if (data != null && data.success == true) {
                window.location = '/'
            }
            else {
                $('#signIn_1').append(data);
                alert(data);
            }

        }
    })

});
```

})(jQuery);

Comment: Thanks comment, Did the return value is not wrong to view files?